# Facebook graph can't retrieve fanpage info

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

Not that long ago this link worked:
http://graph.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/my_fanpage_name
and I was able to get basic information about the page,  likes and shares. Now I see error: "An access token is required". 
Has facebook changed something recently? Is there other way I can get the number of likes of the facebook page without access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use an Access Token for that call now, and you need to specify the fields you want to get:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/my_fanpage_name?fields=name,likes&access_token=xxx
```

You can use an App Access Token, which is just App ID and App Secret with a pipe in the middle:

```
App-ID|App-Secret
```

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

More information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/